# Issues with PHP while statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to run a while statement that will set a column in a mysql database, based on a uniqueID.

I've done this many times, and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong this time.

Basically, it works properly until I actually tell it to save the table. Here is my code

```
$alertAdmin = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE notified='0'");
    $tcheckNotifs = mysqli_num_rows($alertAdmin);

    if($tcheckNotifs > 0) {
        echo "test<br><br>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($alertAdmin))
            {
                $Unique = $row['UniqueID'];
                echo $Unique.' ';
                $sql = "UPDATE tickets SET `notified`='1' WHERE `UniqueID`='$Unique'";
                //mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            }
    }
```

And this works for echoing the UniqueID, and it echos the correct one. The problem comes in when I uncomment the `mysqli_query($con, $sql);`
in which case, nothing inside the loop is echo'd, but it DOES save the database.

For example:
Lets say this while statement loops through and finds 3 iterations of rows that have notified equal to 0 (UniqueID's 29, 26, 25), while the mysqli_query is commented, it will display these numbers on the page just fine. But as soon as I uncomment it, the database will save but it does not display any of the rest of the while loop on the page.

I need this desperately, because I plan to send a desktop notification at the same time the loop is played.

FOLLOW UP:
It also does not display the `echo "test<br><br>";` on the page when the query is uncommented either.

Another follow up:
The query is saving all the data like its meant to. The problem is nothing else inside the tcheckNotifs IF statement are showing (echo's and such), like they aren't being executed. Almost like the end of the while statement is executing before anything else, including the "test" echo before the while statement.

Could anyone help me figure out why this isn't working as expected?

Here is all of my current code, with some suggestions from you guys added in, but still not working properly.
The while statement will save the query, but no other output is shown on the page.

```
$configs = include("config.php");
$con = mysqli_connect($configs['SQL-Host'], $configs['SQL-User'], $configs['SQL-Pass'], $configs['SQL-Database']) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }

        $alertAdmin = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE notified='0'");
        $tcheckNotifs = mysqli_num_rows($alertAdmin);

        if($tcheckNotifs > 0) {
            echo "test<br><br>";
            flush(); ob_flush();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($alertAdmin))
                {
                    $Unique = $row['UniqueID'];
                    echo $Unique.' ';
                    updateTickets($con, $Unique);
                }
            echo "test<br><br>";
        }

        function updateTickets($con, $id){
    $sql = "UPDATE tickets SET notified=1 WHERE UniqueID=$id";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

Comment: use `mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));` in order to see where the query fails

Comment: if you don't get your debug output, then you've got a problem, and most likely display_errors and error_reporting are turned off. turn them on, and try again. plus stop assuming db queries will never fail. at bare minimum, you should have something like `mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: @AlexAndrei The query doesn't fail. It saves the data like it should, but nothing else inside the if statement is shown.

Comment: @MarcB I just hadn't gotten around to adding the mysqli safety net yet, as I was just trying to get it set up to work properly first.

Comment: what else do you have inside that `if` and `while`, post the whole code

Comment: @AlexAndrei I posted the entire statement.

Comment: @AlexAndrei
I posted the entire page.

Comment: did you enable error_reporting as @MarcB suggested?

Comment: @AlexAndrei Yes I did, no errors reported. I did just discover sometthing though, if I remove the check (`if($tcheckNotifs > 0) {`) all data is displayed before the while, but nothing is displayed after. (Also that check is very important, so I'd like to find a way to keep it.)

Comment: show contents of config.php

Comment: @AlexAndrei that just has my database connections in it, and I know they work, because they are used elsewhere in the website - and also the data is saving correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97426/discussion-between-alex-andrei-and-grumpy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FINAL UPDATE**
With the help of [Alex Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5043552/alex-andrei) as well, we moved to PDO

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=domains;host=localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';

try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$st = $db->prepare('SELECT UniqueID FROM tickets WHERE notified=0');
$st->execute();

$result = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $d){
    echo $d['UniqueID'] . "<br/>";
    $id = $d['UniqueID'];
    $st = $db->prepare("UPDATE tickets SET notified=1 WHERE UniqueID=$id");
    $st->execute();
}
```

**SECOND UPDATE**

Try putting your query in a variable and run the loop like this...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($alertAdmin))
    {
        $Unique = $row['UniqueID'];
        echo $Unique.' ';
        $sql = "UPDATE tickets SET notified=1 WHERE UniqueID=$Unique";
        $update = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

There is a chance the query runs first like you said. Maybe you can create an independent function to run the query and call the function from inside the while loop.

```
function updateTickets($con, $id){
    $sql = "UPDATE tickets SET notified=1 WHERE UniqueID=$id";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

And your loop would look like this...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($alertAdmin))
    {
        $Unique = $row['UniqueID'];
        echo $Unique.' ';
        updateTickets($con, $Unique);
    }
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I would modify your query like this...

```
$sql = "UPDATE tickets SET notified=1 WHERE UniqueID=$Unique";
```

You do not need all the back ticks nor single quotes here. Might be causing an issue.

Also, I assume 1 is an integer so no need to quote that.

Comment: The query isn't failing, its saving all the data like its meant to. The problem is nothing else inside the tcheckNotifs IF statement are showing. Almost like the end of the while statement is executing before anything else, including the "test" echo before the while statement.

Comment: same issue. I had to pass $con in the updateTickets function aswell though, so I used `function updateTickets($con, $sql){` and `updateTickets($con, $sql);` - but same issue. Not including the $con made the data display, BUT it didn't save to the database anymore.

Comment: an echo after the while statement still does not display.

Comment: Thought...try putting your query into a variable like `$update = mysqli_query($con, $sql);`

Comment: That has the same result.\

Comment: Have you considered performing a `foreach` loop instead?

Comment: that is definitely an option. I'm not sure how to do that with a mysqli array though.

Answer (score 1):

The Fix: PDO OF COURSE!

```
    $configs = include("config.php");

    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$configs['SQL-Database'].';host='.$configs['SQL-Host'].''; 
    $user = $configs['SQL-User']; 
    $password = $configs['SQL-Pass']; 

    try { 
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password); 
    } catch (PDOException $e) { 
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
    } 

    $st = $db->prepare('SELECT UniqueID FROM tickets WHERE notified=0'); 
    $st->execute(); 

    $result = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach($result as $d){ 
    echo $d['UniqueID'] . "<br/>"; 
    $id = $d['UniqueID']; 
    $st = $db->prepare("UPDATE tickets SET notified=1 WHERE UniqueID=$id"); 
    $st->execute(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> $sql = "UPDATE tickets SET `notified`='1' WHERE `UniqueID`='$Unique'";

The error I think it's here. You can't use `$Unique` between single quotes (although you already are between double quotes).

Try to fixing this replacing the line with:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tickets SET `notified`='1' WHERE `UniqueID`=$Unique";
```

Comment: The query isn't failing, its saving all the data like its meant to. The problem is nothing else inside the tcheckNotifs IF statement are showing. Almost like the end of the while statement is executing before anything else, including the "test" echo before the while statement.

Comment: Probably an infinite loop. Try to force flushing the output buffer inserting `flush();
ob_flush();`
after each echoes.

Comment: By uncommenting the mysqli_query it makes it an infinite loop? That's impossible. It works while that is commented perfectly, and it even works while its uncommented but it doesn't show any of the outputs on the page. It only saves the data in the database.

Comment: @Grumpy Try to flush the output and see the result. I said 'probably', not 'exactly'.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in your query you are passing a string in:  `...WHERE "UniqueID"="$Unique"` because of the quotes around your php variable. So your query looks like this: `WHERE UniqueID = "10"`. Not a big deal but generally if your looking up a number your should drop the quotes.

And i suspect something is causing your query in the loop to fail, so add something to check for errors:

```
if(!$queryResult){
   echo $con->error;
}
```

Run the loop and see if something is causing errors in your query. But really you should get rid of most of the backticks you have in your queries.

Comment: The query isn't failing, its saving all the data like its meant to. The problem is nothing else inside the tcheckNotifs IF statement are showing. Almost like the end of the while statement is executing before anything else, including the "test" echo before the while statement.

Comment: There has to be more to this code than what you are showing.

Comment: That is all of it. It should be a very simple statement, that's why I'm so confused as to why it's not working.

Comment: Although I can't prove it, I have a gut feeling that its the mix of backticks, single and double quotes in your queries that is causing some parsing error.

Comment: A lot of people have said that, but again, the query is not failing. I did however change my $sql to `$sql = "UPDATE tickets SET notified=1 WHERE UniqueID=$Unique";` to no avail.